# Do we have a preposition meaning "divided by" the same way the preposition "times" meaning "multiplied by"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

"**multiply**" is a verb and "**multiplied**" is an adjective while "**times**" (meaning "**multiplied by**") is a preposition

We say

"**2 multiplied by 4 is/equals 8**" or "**2 times 4 is/equals 8**"

"**divide**" is a verb and "**divided**" is an adjective

We say

"**8 divided by 4 is/equals 2**"

Do we have a preposition meaning "**divided by**" the same way the preposition "times" meaning "**multiplied by**"?

Answer (score 4):

Is that not simply "into" or "over"?

"2 into 8 equals 4” or “8 over 4 is 2”

Comment: That's exactly what I was taught in school.

Comment: We also use "by", but it has to be clear from the context that division is intended because it's also used for multiplication.